# Flutter VsCode error: You don't have an extension for debugging YAML

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I get this error each time I try to start my app in VsCode

> You don't have an extension for debugging YAML. Should we find a YAML
> extension in the Marketplace?

It was working before I add a font in pubspec.yaml, restarted my app and it didn't work anymore. I tried to restart VsCode, undo my changes, launch "flutter pub get" many times but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Click on "open a file", then navigate to the main.dart file and then click debug and run.

Answer (score 26):

This mostly happens when you current file is the pubspec.yaml file. Just close or switch the main.dart or any .dart file. And it will work. Worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

Just select `main.dart` file to start your app

Click debug and run.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The reason is that you are clicking on "Run and Debug" when you are at pubspec.yaml file. Just close it and go to main.dart and then Click on "Run and Debug".

Answer (score 4):

Add .vscode/launch.json in your root folder

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "flutter_project", //<- Your Project Name
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    },
    {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    },   
 ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'For that go to RUN > ADD Configuration > Dart & Flutter'

This worked for me! Thanks Joris

Answer (score 1):

Change the active file to main.dart.
Click on the "Debug and Run" button.

or

Click on "Open a File" in VSCode.
Navigate to the main.dart file in your Flutter project.
Click on the "Debug and Run" button.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you current file is the pubspec.yaml file. Just close or switch the main.dart or any .dart file. And it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Dart & Flutter run configuration has to be selected.

For that go to RUN > ADD Configuration > Dart & Flutter