# VS Code Error: "You don't have an extension for debugging YAML. Should we find a YAML extension in the Marketplace?"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, yaml, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to compile a program, and when I try to debug and run the script I get an error that reads "You don't have an extension for debugging YAML. Should we find a YAML extension in the Marketplace?"

I opened VS Code and tried to run the script, but I got the error.

Comment: If this is a Flutter app, this might be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438750/flutter-vscode-error-you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-yaml. See my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter VsCode error: You don't have an extension for debugging YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438750/flutter-vscode-error-you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the necessary language support, and the program you are attempting to compile is in dart, [you may be encountering this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438750/flutter-vscode-error-you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-yaml).

As stated in the linked thread, select `main.dart` so it's the currently active file, then attempt to debug and run. One cause of this error seems to stem from having `pubspec.yaml` as the current file open in VS Code.